# UDP chat program error?

Tags: java, udp, chat

i'm a beginner in programming, so i hope you can help me solve my problem. I'm writing an UDP based chat program,which have a server and client class, and there's no sign of any kind of problem, but when i trying to run the program it throws "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind" public class Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Server:

```
  public class Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

 byte[] serverBuffer,clientBuffer;
 DatagramSocket client,server;
 JTextField textField;
 JTextArea textArea;
 JButton button;


 public Server (){

   this.setSize(400,400);
   this.setTitle("Server");
   textField = new JTextField(100);
   textField.setBackground(Color.white);
   textField.setForeground(Color.black);
   this.add(textField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   textArea = new JTextArea();
   this.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   textArea.setBackground(Color.white);
   textArea.setForeground(Color.green);
   button = new JButton("Send Message");
   this.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   button.addActionListener(this);
   this.setVisible(true);

 serverBuffer = new byte[1024];
 clientBuffer = new byte[1024];

 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try{
        client = new DatagramSocket();
        server = new DatagramSocket(9999);

       while(true){
           DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(clientBuffer,clientBuffer.length);
           server.receive(dataPacket);
           String message = new String(dataPacket.getData());
           textArea.append("\nClient's message:" + message); 

       } 
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try{
        if(e.getActionCommand()=="Send Message"){
       String message = textField.getText();
       serverBuffer = message.getBytes();
       DatagramPacket sendPack = new DatagramPacket(serverBuffer,serverBuffer.length,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),9998);
       client.send(sendPack);
       textArea.append("\nMyself: " + message);
       textField.setText(" ");

     }  
   }catch(Exception a){
       a.printStackTrace();
   }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Server server = new Server();
 }

 }
```

Client:

```
  public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

byte[] clientBuffer,serverBuffer;
DatagramSocket server,client;
String sendData;
JTextField textField;
JTextArea textArea;
JButton button;


public Client(){  

   this.setSize(400,400);
   this.setTitle("Client");
   textField = new JTextField(100);
   textField.setBackground(Color.white);
   textField.setForeground(Color.black);
   this.add(textField,BorderLayout.EAST);
   textArea = new JTextArea();
   this.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   textArea.setBackground(Color.white);
   textArea.setForeground(Color.white);
   button = new JButton("Send Message");
   this.add(button,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   button.addActionListener(this);
   this.setVisible(true);

    serverBuffer = new byte[1024];
    clientBuffer = new byte[1024];

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    try{
        client = new DatagramSocket();
        server = new DatagramSocket(9998);
    while(true){
        DatagramPacket dataPacket = new DatagramPacket(clientBuffer,clientBuffer.length);
        server.receive(dataPacket);
        String message = new String(dataPacket.getData());
        textArea.append("\nServer: " + message);

    }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     try{
         if(e.getActionCommand()=="Send Message"){

        String message = textField.getText();
        clientBuffer = message.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(serverBuffer,serverBuffer.length,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),9999);
        client.send(sendPacket);
        textArea.append("\nClient: " + message);
        textField.setText("");
     }   
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Client obj = new Client();
  }


  }
```

Comment: so what else is running on those ports?

Comment: Make sure you close/release resources when you are done with them.

Comment: Why do you have a client and a server socket each in client and server application? And see that you've closed previous windows. There can be only 1 running application per port.

Comment: When i run the client class i get an errorr message and the server window appears instead of the Client :/

Comment: Zapl! Could you explain how to solve the problem? sorry im really beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you another Server process running? In which case you need to terminate that process and then start it again.

The error means that the socket you are using is already in use, most likely be another java process. Going into Task Manager (if you're on a PC) should help to see what other processes are currently executing.